# Is switch-case execution time variable?

Tags: c, switch-statement, execution-time

Does `switch` statement determines appropriate `case` statement in same execution time for either of possible input values?
Does it compare input value with `case` blocks and jumps to appropriate `case` when upon finding the value that it was looking for?

Consider example below. Does `switch` statement execute in same time for `input = 1` or `input = 256` or does it execute slower for latter value?

```c
int output, input = 256;
    switch( input )
    {   
        case 1:
            output = 1;
            break;
        case 2:
            output = 2;
            break;
        case 4:
            output = 3;
            break;
        case 8:
            output = 4;
            break;
        case 16:
            output = 5;
            break;
        case 32:
            output = 6;
            break;
        case 64:
            output = 7;
            break;
        case 128:
            output = 8;
            break;
        case 256:
            output = 9;
            break;
        default:
            output = 0;
            break;
    }
```

Comment: Could be implementation dependent, but usually a switch statement will be compiled to use a sort of dispatch table, so the position of the case within the statement shouldn't make a difference - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement#Compilation

Comment: There are at least 3 different ways a compiler can implement a `switch` statement. One option is simple compare/branch for each case. So no, you should not expect every case to be handled in the same amount of time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does `switch` statement execute in same time for `input = 1` or `input = 256` or does it execute slower for latter value?

The language does not specify.

Implementations commonly implement *some* `switch` statements with the use of jump tables, which makes the `switch` take approximately the same amount of time regardless of the control value.  However, they may also use multiple branches, exactly as for an `if` / `else if` tree, which takes a longer time to process for some control values than for others.  They may use other strategies as well.

Those that choose among multiple possibilities commonly do so on the basis of the case values that must be supported.